# Widget for website pageviews

Tags: widget, analytics

I need a widget to put up on my website that tracks the number of page views. The following features would be a bonus:

- Google analytics integration
- An option to choose between unique viewers/total page views
- Customisability in terms of colours, size etc.

Plus, it should be lightweight. Which widget would best suit my purpose?

My website is PHP/MySQL based.

Comment: As those are not specified, I think web service is a good assumption. Of course, stating it explicitly would be better.

Comment: Why don't you use Google Analytic solution?

Answer (score -1):

[Freecounterstat](http://www.freecounterstat.com/) should do the trick for you. Although it does not have Google Analytics integration, it does offer about 750 designs for you to choose from and can be resized to fit your needs.

I have used this based on personal experience. I have not noticed any problems or shortcomings when using this widget.

To enable it, just simply put the generated code in your desired page and presto!